# How to make Emacs put access level modifiers in their own indentation level in my C++ code?

Tags: emacs

I want to indent my C++ code in Emacs in way similar to the `"bsd"` style, with one difference: access level modifiers must belong in their own indentation level. (Since I do not use either `switch` or labels/`goto`, it can be said generally that lines ending in a colon must belong in their own indentation level.) Here is an example:

```
 class somewhat
 {
   private:
     int whatever;

   public:
     void somehow()
     {
       if (something_about(whatever))
         like_this();
       else
       {
         std::cerr << "It is not true that something_about("
                   << whatever << ").";
         like_that();
       }
     }
 };
```

How do I configure my `~/.emacs` to reflect this preference? Here is my current configuration:

```
; No tabs at all.
(setq indent-tabs-width nil)
(setq tab-width         2)

; [C-like languages]-specific configuration.
(setq c-basic-offset  2)
(setq c-default-style "bsd")

; Configuration for other languages.
; ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the `access-label` indentation in your `c-offsets-alist`.
I recommend you make a new 'style' with its own `c-offsets-alist` and add a line like:

`(access-label . +)`

If you want to derive from `bsd` style, you can do something like this:

```
(c-add-style "modified-bsd"
'("bsd"
  (c-basic-offset . 2)
  ;;...MORE MODS...
  (c-offsets-alist
   (access-label . +))))`
```

Also, how did I find the offset to modify?  Go to the relevant line of code and press
<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> to show the syntactic analysis of CC-mode.  Also be sure to check the help for `c-offsets-alist`.

Comment: It was `access-label` instead of `case-label`, but thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: ah, great. i swear my eyes saw switch+case :) i'll update the answer.