# Customized google-c-style.el

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I am using [google-c-style.el](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el) to indent my c++ programs.Functions in classes will be indented as below:
[image]

Which is not what I want, I'd like this one:

[image]

Here is my setting in .emacs:

> (setq c-default-style "linux")
>
> (setq c-basic-offset 4)
>
> (require 'cc-mode)
>
> (require 'google-c-style)
>
> (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-make-newline-indent)

Comment: While in your mode, hit C-c C-o Enter to change the indentation offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you also need:

`(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style)`

Currently, even though you `require` google-c-style, it's not adding the style until that defun above is called.  The docstring says it's meant to be added to the hook as well.

---

More generally, for indenting issues you need to know about `c-offsets-alist`

It allows you to customize how indentation is performed on different syntactic elements.
An easy way to figure out which element you need to modify is to go to the location (e.g. brace open of `fun()` in your example) and hit <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> for `c-show-syntactic-information`

Rather than use this google-style script, personally I would derive from it or another c-style and override the values to suit my taste.

For instance, I notice you expect a c-basic-offset of 4, but google-style uses a c-basic-offset of 2, so you could derive from and override the Google style to replace c-basic-offset.

Check out: [How to make Emacs put access level modifiers in their own indentation level in my C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179700/how-to-make-emacs-put-access-level-modifiers-in-their-own-indentation-level-in-m/14182017#14182017) for an example.